# Is it possible to make curvature of sine wave equal to that of a parabola?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, conic-sections, transformation, curvature

Suppose there is a symmetric parabola pointing downwards now we only consider the part above the x axis so is it possible to make curvature of sine wave equal to that part above x axis
So that it coincides with that part of parabola above x axis sorry if this question makes no sense please don't close it if i was not able to make this more understandable then i will edit it

Comment: What do you think it means to make the curvature of the sine wave equal to part of a parabola? Do you want a function that is periodic like the sine but made of pieces of parabolas? Do you just want the curvatures to be equal at one point (and if so, which one)?

Comment: Yes david k i want to make a sine wave equal to part of a parbola

Comment: A sine wave curves up in some places and down in others. Your parabola only curves down. What do you _really_ want, exactly?

Comment: I want the part of cosine wave from -π/2 to π/2 to coincide with the part of parabola above x axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally you can make a sine wave and a parabola agree to second order.  The Taylor series of the cosine (which is a shifted sine wave) is $1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^4}{4!}+\ldots$.  The first two terms make a parabola centered at $0$ with a maximum of $1$.  As long as you are close enough to $0$ that the $\frac {x^4}{4!}$ term is negligible, they will agree.  The agreement is not exact.  The [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20%7Bcos%28x%29%2C%201-x%5E2%2F2%7D) plot below shows they match very closely out to $\pm \frac 12$, and rather well out to $\pm 1$

[image]

Comment: Ross milikan how do i make it more accurate i mean make the sine wave touch the parabola at its zeroes

Comment: If you do that the curvatures around the vertex will not match.  You need to define clearly, which you have not done at all, what is important to you.  For a rough idea you can count how many constraints you are imposing.  If you want the values, slopes, and curvature to match at a point, that is three constraints.  That is what I matched here.  You can match three constraints with a parabola because it has three parameters.  If you want to match a couple of zeros as well, that is five constraints, so you need a quartic.

Comment: As an exercise, you should find a parabola that goes through the three points of the cosine wave $(-\pi,0), (0,1), (\pi, 0)$.  Because the functions are even there is no linear term in the parabola.  Then plot it and see it does not match nearly as well near $x=0$

Comment: Actually i wanted to transform motion of a freefall . Suppose an object falls freely and bounces off elastically and rises to same height and goes down and again rise......now there is not a single function that depicts it path at any instant but since a sine and cosine wave are periodic therefore it would be useful to depict the path of such freefall and i think if we do this then we will lack accuracy in values

Comment: A sine wave can match the top quite well, but it cannot match the bottom because of the corner at the bounce.  There is a sharp corner that a sine wave will never match.  You can Fourier analyze the plot and express it as the sum of a series of sine waves.   Depending on your purpose, *much* better because it only takes one term, is to find the period of the motion.  Given a time, find the time since the last bounce and find the position from that.  That will be a simple parabola.

Comment: Thanks a lot ross milikan everyone in this community is so nice better than physics stack exchange community where they just close your question everytime