# If a circle and parabola touch each other and also have common root then what's the relationship between their coefficient?

Tags: circles, graphing-functions, conic-sections, mathematical-physics, tangent-line

Actually this question is from physics (projectile motion) but i believe its related more to maths here equation of parabola
$$y=ax-5x^2-5(ax)^2$$
And that of circle
$$x^2+y^2=(a/5(1+a^2))^2$$ where $a=\tan \theta$ link to original question
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562407
Now they touch each other also they share a common root now we have to find the values of a
Now this seems nonsense but if we add slider on graph to a then they seem to meet the required condition at $theta$ approximately equal to $73^\circ$ also no boundattion for initial velocity so ignore the $40 \space m/s$ velocity in graph we can take it $1\ m/s$ also
[[image: the graph image please note that a here in image is <span class=]$\theta$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBbgK.jpg)

But how do we prove that when $\theta=(\approx)73^\circ$ the circle and parabola meet the required condition of touching each other and having a common root as shown in graph please help me

Comment: I have made the graph , made equations  before and tried atleast three hours before asking here

Comment: Yes, I can see that but it's not clear to me what you want to prove

Comment: I have edited sir please check now

Comment: Thank you sir please tell me how can i improve this question here to reopen it https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3729581/802238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r = \dfrac{a}{5(a^2+1)}$ be the radius of the circle (the way you wrote it is a bit ambiguous, but this is what you need for the parabola and circle to intersect at $x=r, y=0$).
The resultant of $x^2 + y^2 - r^2$ and $y - (a x - 5 (1+a^2) x^2)$ with respect to $y$ is
$${\frac { \left(  \left( 5\,{a}^{2}+5 \right) x-a \right) 
 \left(  \left( 125\,{a}^{6}+375\,{a}^{4}+375\,{a}^{2}+125 \right) {x}
^{3}+ \left( -25\,{a}^{5}-50\,{a}^{3}-25\,a \right) {x}^{2}+ \left( 5
\,{a}^{2}+5 \right) x+a \right) }{ 25 \left( {a}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
This must be $0$ where the two curves intersect.  The first factor in the numerator is $0$ at $x = r$, so the other factor in the numerator gives the other intersection.  Now for the curves to be tangent at that point, we want this to have discriminant $0$ with respect to $x$.  That discriminant turns out to be
$$ (62500 (a^4-11 a^2-1)) (a^2+1)^6$$
so the value of $a$ must be the (positive real) root of $a^4 - 11 a^2 - 1$, which is
$$ \sqrt{(11 + 5 \sqrt{5})/2} \approx 3.330190676 $$
This is $\arctan(\theta)$ where $\theta \approx 1.279079822$ radians or $73.28587546$ degrees.

Comment: Robert israel how can i thank you you you are a hero!

Comment: Sir please explain the steps after 8th step what is resultant is it the resultant in algebra theory which we say that two polynomial with resultant equal to zero when when they have a common root?

Comment: Yes, that is the resultant.

Comment: *This is $\arctan(\theta)$.* You mean $\tan(\theta)$.