# How can we erase graph of $f(x)=-10a((x/a)-[x/a])$ from specific parts?

Tags: graphing-functions, book-recommendation, transformation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The function
$$f(x)=-10a(\frac{x}{a}-[\frac{x}{a}])$$
I want to erase some parts of graph from $x=a$ to $2a$ and from 3a to 4a ... And so on
How can i accomplish that? I have no idea of how can we do that also please suggest any resource from which i can learn these transformation

Comment: Sorry everyone if you think this was a silly question then please tell me some resources from where i can learn transformation

Comment: Do you have an image of the graph?  If so, you need a graphics program, not math.  Do you mean something different by $\div$ as opposed to $/$?  If you just want the function undefined on those intervals, you can use cases  $f(x)=\begin {cases} \text{undefined}& a\lt x \lt 2a\\\text{undefined}& 3a\lt x \lt 4a\\ -10a((x÷a)-[x÷a]) & \text {otherwise} \end {cases}$

Comment: Sir i want to undefine it so that everyone could make this diagram without a computer program

Comment: Then my statement above is just what you need.  It clearly shows the regions where the function is undefined.  You can think about whether the less than signs should be less than or equal

Comment: By ÷ sign i want to indicate fraction

Comment: We usually use stacked fractions, like \frac xa which gets $\frac xa$ or the slash to give $x/a$ rather than $\div$.  $\div$ is rare enough that people will worry it may be integer divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a piecewise-defined function:

$\forall\ \text{even } n\ge0$,

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\text{undefined}&a(n+1)<x<a(n+2)\\-10a\left(\frac xa-\left[\frac xa\right]\right)&\text{for all other values of }x\end{cases}$

Not sure if it is the right notation but I basically want $n$ to be all the even whole numbers so that $x$ is between every odd multiple of $a$ starting with $a$ to $2a$.

Also, $-10a\left(\frac xa-\left[\frac xa\right]\right)$ simplifies down to zero for $a\ne0$ just in case you didn't know.